# Placing an image on SWF

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, css

I have an SWF file for my website banner. On this SWF, my website name is displayed on the left hand side. Now I changed my website name and I want to place the image having my new website name on the specific place. I don't want to cover the whole SWF.

You can check the SWF with the following code.

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0" width="999" height="130">
    <param name="movie" value="http://bankingmadeasy.com/swf/Movie1.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <embed src="http://bankingmadeasy.com/swf/Movie1.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="999" height="130"></embed>
</object>
```

Now I want to display `aspireeducation.net` instead of `bankingmadeasy.com`.
How can I do this?

Comment: Why can't you just modify the swf? Or are you asking how to overlay an image using html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do it.
Browsers place swf above all other html elements. You can, however, modify the flash file and upload a new swf.

--EDIT---

I have done it and can send you the swf if you tell me your email id

Attached preview:

[image: Preview]

Comment: @Deepak I can do it for you if you want me to.

Comment: Hello Pranav plz send me this to my email id dpkchhirang@gmail.com or chhirang.deepak@gmail.com

Comment: Let me look for it, I think I deleted it in a recent cleanup

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, check http://www.brianyerkes.com/swfobject-help-when-placing-a-div-over-flash/